# Set cookies on client from server side Nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, app-router

I have a server side component (nextjs 13 app router)

```
import WidthWrapper from "@/components/WidthWrapper";
import { brandQuery } from "@/api/brand";

const BrandsContainer = async () => {
  const { data, status } = await brandQuery();

  if (!status) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <WidthWrapper
      className={
        "grid grid-cols-4 md:grid-cols-8 gap-[10px] p-[20px] md:p-[10px]"
      }
    >
      {data?.map((brand) => (
        <BrandsItem image={brand.image} />
      ))}
    </WidthWrapper>
  );
};
export default BrandsContainer;
```

brandQuery is simple fetch

How can I set browser cookie in this component?

Answer (score 0):

Look into cookies-next library. npm i cookies-next